RecyclerView scrolling above Sticky SearchView in Android XML Layout
I'm working on an Android XML layout using CoordinatorLayout and NestedScrollView where I have the following child views in order: ViewPager, TabLayout, SearchView, and RecyclerView.
I want to achieve the following behavior:
When the screen is scrolled up, the SearchView should stick to the top of the screen.
The RecyclerView should remain below the SearchView and have its own independent scrolling behavior, rather than scrolling above the SearchView.
Currently, my RecyclerView is scrolling above the SearchView, which is not the intended behavior.
Here is my XML layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/view_pager_height" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                app:tabIndicator="@null"
                app:tabRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
                app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                style="@style/NoTabLayoutShadow" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:queryHint="Search..."
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_search_view"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/floating_action_button"
        android:src="@drawable/stats" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

